# How to make docker only use a private network to communicate with other hosts?

Tags: networking, docker, private-ip

Digital Ocean provides internal IPs that are not traffic-metered.  How can I configure Docker to exclusively use this private network? How to make the network interface that the docker creates `docker0` only use the private network?

Answer (score 1):

from DO pricing page: "Each droplet is billed per hour up to its monthly cap."

You want to use traffic in internal DO network.
Just create on each droplet interface with internal address and route your traffic into them.

General question - general answer.
Please, clarify - what is the problem ?
How to create internal interface ? How to route it ? Anything else ?

Comment: It is updated. Excuse me.